# Name of department, Name of Manager, Number of employees who have salaries above average of the department

Tags: sql, join, select

I want help with this question

provide a select statement that shows:
Name of department, Name of Manager, Number of employees who have salaries
above average of the department.

The table which we used the basic table in Scott and tiger ( emp, dept ) I try this code :

```
   select d.dname , count (e.deptno) no_emp

   from emp e, dept d
  where e.deptno=d.deptno 
    and 
       e.sal >( select avg(sal) sal 
        from emp 

        where m.deptno=e.deptno 

        Group by m.deptno) 

       Group by e.deptno,d.dname
```

And I haven’t completed answer the name of manger  doesn’t appear:

| Dname | No_emp |
| --- | --- |
| ACCOUNTING | 1 |
| RESEARCH | 3 |
| SALES | 2 |

I try also this code :

```
select    d.dname, count(e.deptno) no_emp, e.ename mgr_dept 
from      emp e, dept d
where     e.deptno = d.deptno 
and       e.ename in 
     (select      ename 
      from        emp 
      where       job=‘MANAGER’ ) 
And       e.sal > 
     (select      avg(sal) sal 
      from        emp 
      where       m.deptno = e.deptno 
      Group by    m.deptno) 
Group by  e.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
```

The result does not true:

| DNAME | NO_EMP | MGR_DEPT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RESEARCH | 1 | JONES |
| SALES | 1 | BLAKE |

Comment: >> the name of manger doesn’t appear:  Look at the first line of your query:  `select d.dname , count (e.deptno) no_emp`  all you ask for is dname and a count of deptno (which you call no_emp).  You need to add the manger name column (something like m.ename, i guess) to your query.

Comment: I try but it didn’t work because I tried this condition e.job=‘MANGER’  to give me the manger of dept   , it gave the count equal to one dependent on previous condition

Comment: select d.dname ,e.ename as mg_dept , count (e.deptno) no_emp

   from emp e, dept d
  where e.deptno=d.deptno and e.job=‘MANGER’
    and 
       e.sal >( select avg(sal) sal 
        from emp 

        where m.deptno=e.deptno 

        Group by m.deptno) 

       Group by e.deptno,d.dname

Comment: OK, so add the new query and the result you got to your question.  Next, what happens when you run the inner query by itself (everything between 'select avg(sal)' and 'group by m.deptno')

Comment: The result for Inner query is correct it gave the average sal for every dept

Answer (score 0):

Here's 2 methods

**1) Join to a sub-query that calculates the employees with above average salary.**

> ```
> SELECT
>   dep.dname as department
> , mgr.ename as manager
> , depstat.above_average_salary
> FROM DEPT dep
> LEFT JOIN EMP mgr 
>   ON mgr.deptno = dep.deptno
>   AND mgr.job = 'MANAGER'
> JOIN (
>     SELECT deptno, COUNT(empno) as above_average_salary
>     FROM EMP e1
>     WHERE sal > (SELECT AVG(sal) 
>                  FROM EMP e2 
>                  WHERE e2.deptno = e1.deptno)
>     GROUP BY deptno
> ) depstat ON depstat.deptno = dep.deptno
> ORDER BY dep.dname
> ```
>
> ```
> DEPARTMENT | MANAGER | ABOVE_AVERAGE_SALARY
> :--------- | :------ | -------------------:
> ACCOUNTING | CLARK   |                    1
> RESEARCH   | JONES   |                    3
> SALES      | BLAKE   |                    2
> ```

**2) Using conditional aggregation**

> ```
> SELECT
>   dep.dname as department
> , MAX(CASE WHEN emp.job = 'MANAGER'
>       THEN emp.ename END) as manager
> , COUNT(CASE WHEN emp.sal > depstat.avg_sal 
>         THEN emp.empno END) as above_average_salary
> FROM DEPT dep
> LEFT JOIN EMP emp 
>   ON emp.deptno = dep.deptno
> JOIN (
>     SELECT deptno, AVG(sal) as avg_sal
>     FROM EMP
>     GROUP BY deptno
> ) depstat ON depstat.deptno = dep.deptno
> GROUP BY dep.deptno, dep.dname
> ORDER BY dep.dname
> ```
>
> ```
> DEPARTMENT | MANAGER | ABOVE_AVERAGE_SALARY
> :--------- | :------ | -------------------:
> ACCOUNTING | CLARK   |                    1
> RESEARCH   | JONES   |                    3
> SALES      | BLAKE   |                    2
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b22a00d54a0527d1f402587d24188aa)*

There's a difference though.
The first method will show every manager.
The second method assumes that there's only 1 manager per department.

Comment: Thaaaaank you very much  Iam very appreciate

Comment: @ala Btw, have you noticed that the OPERATIONS department isn't in the result? That's because they don't have employees in the EMP table, and it's not a LEFT JOIN to the depstat sub-query.

Comment: Yeah I know it haven’t any employee. Thank you